# Python 3 - Priority Queue - Search and Delete an item by value with O(log(n))

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, priority-queue

I am implementing a `priority queue` in python 3 using [`queue.PriorityQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) like this-

```
from queue import PriorityQueue

class PqElement(object):
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.val = value

    #Custom Compare Function (less than or equsal)
    def __lt__(self, other):
        """self < obj."""
        return self.val > other.val

    #Print each element function
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'PQE:{self.val}'

#Usage-
pq = PriorityQueue()
pq.put(PqElement(v))       # Add Item      - O(Log(n))
topValue = pq.get()        # Pop top item  - O(1)
topValue = pq.queue[0].val # Get top value - O(1)
pqSize = pq.qsize()        # Provide Queue Size - O(1)
isEmpty = pq.empty()       # Is PQ is empty
```

I like to search and delete an item in the priority queue with O(log(n)).

I am wondering if there is any way of doing that?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: "search and delete an item" Why are you trying to search a priority queue?

Comment: I need to know if the item exists in the priority queue. Searching is optional, but I need deletion

Comment: Is using ```queue.PriorityQueue``` a necessity? Also, what might be the order of total number of insertions/deletions?

Comment: I need to delete from a `PriorityQueue`, it is not necessary that I have to use this library for priority queue, it can be another library like `heapq`

Comment: How many total insertions/deletions might the program do? I have an approach, but to gauge its efficiency I need the magnitude of insertions/deletions

Comment: may be 2 to 2^24

Comment: Would you delete the elements by value, or by index?

Comment: I want to delete by value @AbhinavMathur